# Post Auto Draft Issue

Tags: attachments, save-post, draft

I've made custom post type without title and editor and I use custom taxonomies, custom fields and attachments to form a post. My title is generated from custom taxonomies and custom fields (or "ID #" if nothing else is set). Here's title code (could use some polishing probably):

```
function custom_post_type_title ( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'cars' ) {
        $autos = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'brand');
            $brand= '';
            $model= '';
                foreach ( $autos as $auto ) {
                    if ( $auto->parent == 0) {
                        $brand = ' '.$auto->name;
                    } else {
                        $model .= ' '.$auto->name;
                    }
                }
        $engine = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Engine', true);
        if ($engine != '') { $engine = ', '.$engine.'l'; }
        $title = $brand.$model.$engine;
        if ($title == '') { $title = 'ID '.$post_id; }
        $slug = sanitize_title('id-'.$post_id.$brand.$model.$engine);
        $where = array( 'ID' => $post_id );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $title, 'post_name' => $slug), $where );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'cars_save_post');
function cars_save_post($post_id) {
        if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && ! DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
        add_action('publish_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
}
```

Problem is, if I attach an image and navigate away from the post, post will be saved, but won't apear as draft in my post list. The only way (that I know of) I can reach it - thru media's "attached to" link.

Not sure if it's a bug or what, but I would like to see those posts in my Manage Posts list. Any solutions?

**EDIT:**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Just try this scenario:

- Add New Post (regular post will do);
- Upload an Image to it;
- Keep everything else empty;
- Do not save the post;
- Leave the page;

Now if you'll check your Posts page, you won't find an "Auto Draft" in it.
But if you'll check your Media page, image you uploaded just now, will be attached to "Auto Draft", which you can access from there. Even if you delete that image, that post will stay.

I just want to keep my server clean, so if Author made a mistake and forgot to save his post, he should have an easy access to that post via Posts Page.

So my question was, is this a bug and how can I fix it (display "Auto Drafts" in authors Posts page)?

Comment: How do you "set" your title? If you don't populate the field upon save, you propably can't see it. I guess you're adding the title only on output/template?

Comment: Title is fine, even that draft get's correct title (ID #). Updated my question with code. If it's done via regular posts, post is named "Auto Draft", but same issue remains.

Comment: Deactivate your plugins step by step and see if it remains. If it does, switch back to TwentTen. If this solves it, start takin one file out of your theme after the other until you found the cause. Then start writing `return` after the first code block until you find the one that makes your problems.

Comment: I think it's default WordPress behavior. I deactivated all plugins and switched to 2010 and nothing changed. Posts with attachments but without title or content are not displayed in post list, but are saved under "Auto Draft" name (can be seen in Media's "Attached to" column).

Comment: I remember that I had the problem myself and stopped trying to get around it. You have to auto-populate your title upon save as i said in the first comment.

Comment: Well, as you can see in my question, I do populate it upon save. But the problem apears when I do not (forget to) save that post (close window, navigate away from the posts etc.). And even then title is getting populated (named "ID ###" instead of "Auto Draft").

Comment: You don't really do that. Add the following: `if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { /* do stuff */ }`...

Comment: Could you show my how it's done with my current code as an answer? I've tried and failed. I'm not very good with coding :)

Comment: When looking at your code in detail, then there are plenty of other problems starting with `$ex` is not set, etc. Please first go to your wp-config.php and set `define( 'WP_DEBUG',   true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',  true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG',  true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` before doing anything else...

Comment: Well, I set `model` and `brand` to '' and removed `ext` (updated my code). But I'm still not sure how to include `DOING_AUTOSAVE` correctly.

Comment: Wrap your save post add_action call into a function that you hook into init and set `if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && ! DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;` before your add action.

Comment: Updated my code, but nothing has changed. I'm probably doing something wrong :) Also getting `Notice: Use of undefined constant DOING_AUTOSAVE - assumed 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' in ...`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to modify the columns displayed in your Custom Post posts list, so that the list isn't dependent solely on Post Title.

I have a similar situation, with a Custom Post Type that consists solely of a "featured image" (and a "link" custom metabox). I modified the Post list to output the image, which linked to the edit-post page.

You may need to do something similar.